# Save as option while uploading file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm not sure whether it is possible or not to do. I'm uploading the file to a server in my MVC web application. Currently, it is storing in my project folder.
Here is my code which is working fine.

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    try
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Documents"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }

        TempData["Message"] = "Upload successful";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Upload failed";
        return RedirectToAction("Uploads");
    }
}
```

[image]

Now I need to store the file on a File server with providing an option to the user to create a directory and store the file where they want. For that, I need to provide SAVE AS option.
How can I store on file server in the network and how to provide Save As option while uploading?

Comment: Why would you want to give the user the option to generate folders on **your** server? And what would be the point?

Comment: The requirement is like that. As it is separate shared a file server, everyone will save according to their convenience I guess.

Comment: Then just add a textbox so the user can enter a folder name and combine that with your file server path

Comment: If I provide textbox as you said, there are two drawbacks I can see.. First, User will not be able to create sub directories in the main directory(like date wise or category wise) and second, if the name entered in textbox does not match with their existing directory then It will create a new unnecessary directory. This can create problem while downloading the file.

Comment: Point 1. What makes you think you cannot create sub folders (of course you can). Point 2. You can provide a dropownlist for selecting existing folders if necessary. (but none of this really makes any sense)

Comment: Sorry about that but I still not understand why it is not making sense to you. If I'm storing the file on shared file server, I would like to create my own folders and subfolders to store my files in an organized manner. and If the textbox will act as a directory name, then how we can create sub directory( by providing directory/subdirectory in textbox itself)?

Comment: By combining the value with `Server.MapPath("~/Documents")` so that you create a virtual folder `.../Documents/SubFolderName/FileName`. But again what is the point? It makes no difference where the files are - the link that you create for other users to download the files can be whatever path you want - those users don't care what the subfolder name is

Comment: Yes, that makes sense to me. They want to share these servers with other location's team. They want it like that. But I think I can convince them now I guess. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to give the user that level of control out-of-the-box; you can, however, allow the user to specify the path in a separate textbox, and use that to determine the directory path.  OR, it really sounds like what some shared hosters do, which is provide a tree view UI of the folder structure they have access to, they select a folder, and then that directory path is passed back to the server and the file is written to that directory.  There is no built-in component to do everything I mentioned (though there are treeview controls around).  If there is a complete product, it's probably a paid version.